# Not able to convert byte[] to Bitmap in onPreviewFrame() callback method

Tags: android, bitmap

I am not able to convert a byte array to a Bitmap in the preview callback method. I'm using the following code:

```
public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data , 0, data.length);
    Mat orig = new Mat(bmp.getHeight(),bmp.getWidth(),CvType.CV_8UC3);
    Bitmap myBitmap32 = bmp.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
    Utils.bitmapToMat(myBitmap32, orig);
}
```

bmp is null. Please justify how to convert bitmap image.

Comment: is your byte[] have value??

Comment: yes i have value in byte array..